# communication between JS modal windows (popups)

Tags: javascript

what would be, in your opinion, the best way (or some ways) to communicate between **MODAL A** and **MODAL B**? - They **DO NOT** exist together at the same time. one opens the other.

---

[image]

---

### What needs to happen:

(in this very specific case, but there was many cases)

that **MODAL A** triggered (opened) **MODAL B**, in which the user is choosing things from a list, and then, after applying, he will be sent back to **MODAL A** (basically the last modal which trigger the current modal) and now **MODAL A** will need to show the data that was chosen from **MODAL B**.

### Ways to pass data from B to A:

- Using some sort of temporary localstorage or some shared memory object that *MODAL A* will always check when it is launched, and act upon (then clear it). This object will always store any data that might be needed in another popup, and if some popup needs data which relates to another, that popup would know to check that object for the things it needs.
- *MODAL B* will pass some data directly to the MODAL it should open via some data that will be attached to the button which opens the callback, which looks like this btw:
  `<a data-modal="lastModal">Continue</a>`

Do you have any other ideas? maybe better ones?

---

### Update

At the end what I did was to store in-memory the closed modal window (that one which triggers MODAL B) and use custom events to publish any data that the controller of MODAL A will be subscribed to, and will change the view of it accordingly, while the DOM is in-memory, so once MODAL A is restored from my history array of modals, it will already be updated. one all modals are closed, the history object is cleared.

Comment: are these separate windows or within the same context (e.g.: JS driven modals)?

Comment: yes JS modal windows. they are a part of a modal system I am designing. these two modal are completely separate from each-other, and act likes independent units, BUT can also trigger one another and interact.

Comment: Has the modal B a controller?

Comment: They both have their own controller

Answer (score 0):

This is solved on other GUI platforms using events. You can broadcast out data for other areas to receive so you can scale your modal instances without having them be dependent on hard-coded keys or object literals.

Modal A can be listening to an event **modal.capture-data** while Modal B can be emitting event **modal.capture-data** when the apply button is clicked.

Now as you add more modals into this, you may want to add some credential check or specific events to determine when to apply the data received.

Also there are ton of JS libraries that handle custom events: jQuery, Angular (based on `$scope/$rootScope`), or EventEmitter.

Comment: but how can one listen to the other if only one modal exist in any given time? I only have a single modal and it's view is updated according the the one it needs to present to the user. once the user opened a modal FROM some modal, it replaces the modal originated it.

Comment: If this process is all running on the same thread in the same context, both controllers should be active regardless of what's presented to the user unless your destructing/constructing controllers on-the-fly.

Comment: yes I am exactly doing this. they are re-constructed when they are needed. It worked great till I needed this specific communication. I can modify the architecture so they will never "die". now they are just..functions that are triggered as callbacks when a certain popup is opened, and I know exactly which controller to fire for which.

Answer (score -1):

**Update:**
Since you say you dont use angular. Here is another aproche.

***Global function but not recomended***:

Make a global function that perform the desire update and when the checkbox is click, execute that function.

```
function UpdateModalAbackgroundImage(imageUrl)
{
// update here...
}
```

Now when you click over the checkbox execute that function.

```
// I suppose your are using jquery at least
$('.mycheckboxs').click(function(){
// some logic

UpdateModalAbackgroundImage(mycustomurl)// since is global, you can execute it.
});
```

Just make sure that the **UpdateModalAbackgroundImage** function is defined at the moment of appending modal B to the body.

Comment: Ooops... Well, would be the same them. I'll edit my answer in this case